How to show image in report
I have image stored in odoo 8 module_name > static > img > image1.png
I want to show the image in rml report, so i'm using this script but the image does not showing
<image x="1.3cm" y="27.7cm" height="40.0" file="/static/img/image1.png"></image>

What is the correct script to show the image in rml report? Thank you

Did you already try to use an absolute URI instead of the relative one?

Odoo will first use an absolute path to get the image then will try the relative paths to: rml file, addons, and openerp
In the case of relative path, using ../static/img/image1.png (the RML file is inside a folder at the same level as the static folder) should work.

thank you for your help sir but it still no image showing

The path above is taken from an Odoo 8 module. Where did you put the image file?
